# How to type cast a masterViewController when using splitViewControllers

Tags: casting, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I've got the following code:

```
guard let splitViewController = self.window?.rootViewController
          as? UISplitViewController else {
          fatalError("Missing SplitViewController")
        }

        guard let masterNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first
          as? UINavigationController,
          let masterViewController = masterNavController.topViewController
          as?  MasterViewController else {
          fatalError("Missing MasterViewController")
        }

        splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden
        splitViewController.delegate = masterViewController
```

I've read and understood the relevant swift.org reference, yet I don't know what I should conditionally type cast masterViewController constant as. I'm getting 'MasterViewController is an undeclared type' compiler error.

Comment: Show us the code where you declare `MasterViewController`.

Comment: That is my problem, I don't know how to declare it. I didn't declare it, and I assume the splitViewController instance has a class type somewhere that I can use as the conditional downcast.

Comment: If you didn't declare it anywhere, then it's just a plain old `UIViewController`. You need to specify what kind of VCs a split view controller manages, either in code or in your storyboard.